# Search in text file. Error: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, text, typeerror

sorry I`m pretty new in Python. Trying to print all lines containing substring "error" from the text file, using regular expressions. 
Getting type error, any suggestions please?

```
import re
errors = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile("error", re.IGNORECASE)  # Compile a case-insensitive regex
with open ('Setup.log', 'rt') as myfile:    
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:      # If a match is found 
            errors.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
for err in errors:                            # Iterate over the list of tuples
    print("Line " + str(err[0]) + ": " + err[1])
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-efb36dfad1d6> in <module>()
      9             errors.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
     10 for err in errors:                            # Iterate over the list of tuples
---> 11     print("Line " + str(err[0]) + ": " + err[1])

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? I guess that you use "str" or "print" as variable to hold a string somewhere. Rename the variable.

Comment: Yeah, I used it in one place above, I changed it, but forger to recompile notebook.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `str`  as variable to hold a string somewhere above.
Just need to rename the variable